# visual studio fast typing string inside brackets

Tags: visual-studio

**In Visual Studio** 
while i am typing a **string** inside braces
what is the hotkey to go to ending bracket `]` without pressing <kbd>end</kbd>

```
item["i am typing here..."] //i want an hotkey to jump here
```

**if it's not possible**
how can i jump out of current box which i am typing in?

```
namespace{
  class{
    method(){
      lambda->({(jump out of this box)});
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

according to this https://www.dofactory.com/reference/visual-studio-shortcuts you should use end button  to go to ending bracket  and you can see all of hotkeys in this link.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Ctrl-]`. From the documentation:

> Moves the cursor to the matching brace in the document. If the cursor is on an opening brace, this will move to the corresponding closing
>   brace and vice versa

At the bottom line - it will bring you to the end of your current braces-scope (or to the beginning of it if you are on the closing brace )

Comment: I don't think there is a shortcut to escape the sting. Isn't `End` close enough?

Comment: to press end button i should move my right hand , should be an hotkey out there ,there was sth in intellijidea , i think tab , maybe , if i am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I did this trick **after starting to type inside quotes** ("") 
**press** <kbd>tab</kbd> then **press** <kbd>]</kbd> 
It's much better than pressing <kbd>end</kbd> 
Sometimes this won't work and will print **/t** character
I don't know how to deal with that
Still, there should be a better answer to this!